# Im trying to make a partners command for my bot in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command

It keep giving me this error and I don't know what to do. Im fairly new to coding, but I have a little experience doing it before but I have no idea what this means or how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated :) [My screenshot of the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6uL3.png)

Comment: Include your code as codeblocks, not external links

Comment: Remove the double quotes around the word "Paradise"

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, it's more useful to post the code as text than as a screenshot. But looking at what you've got; it looks like because you've got speech marks in the text, you need to "escape" them. For example:

```
const x = "This is a string with "speech marks" - done wrong";
```

Will fail, whereas:

```
const x = "This is a string with \"speech marks\" - done right"
```

Will work because the backslash escapes the speech marks.

See [the w3Schools JavaScript strings page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) for more examples.

Comment: Using backticks (`\``) or single quotes will also work.


`\`This is a string with "speech marks" - done right\``




Also you seem to be making it like C++. Remember this is JavaScript which only uses `var`, `let`, and `const` for strings

Comment: Of course - I've been using Blazor a lot recently, so my brain was still in C# mode; either way, the principle is still the same.

Comment: I edited it to prevent confusion, though most people would have still understood the concept